# Create new metric in Google Data Studio to Count Only Branded KW Impression

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I'm trying to get a count of my branded/unbranded impressions in Google Data Studio and running into a snag when I try to create a new field:

```
Case
   when REGEXP_MATCH(Query,'will enter branded KWs here')
   then count(Impressions)
End
```

This, of course, doesn't work, but wondering if there is any workaround to get what I'm trying to. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be achieved by [Reaggregation](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9429470) (Blending a Data Source with itself); The Sample Google Search Console Data Source has disabled field editing (thus unable to test the proposed solution), however, adding a link to a [Similar Solution for a Google Analytics Post, which includes a GIF of the process](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/28281270?hl=en&msgid=28372757).

**0) Disaggregation**
The metrics in Google Analytics, Ads, etc are currently pre aggregated (the reason it's coloured blue), thus it needs to be disaggregated in order to perform the calculation required. There are two ways: One is using a [Data Extract](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9019969) and the other is a Data Blend (used in this example: #1 below)

***1) Blended Data Source (Reaggragation)***
Create a Blended Data Source by using the following fields:
- ***Join Key #1***: Date
- ***Join Key #2***: Query
- ***Metric***: Impressions

**2) Time Series Chart**
- ***Dimension***: Date
***- Metric***: Impressions_Branded

**3) Impressions_Branded ([Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685))**

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Query, 'will enter branded KWs here') THEN Impressions
END
```